# acessing docker container ip with its name in nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm running one container nginx_cont for frontend and one container web_cont for backend.

I would like my nginx in my frontend container to reach my backend container by its name with

```
proxy_pass http://web_cont:8000;
```

I've tried with the container ip and it is working. I 've tried with the name web_cont_1 as my docker-compose is adding number. And i've tried with web_cont_1.spa_network as I have specified  `networks: spa_network:` in my docker-compose.yml.
I get the error :

```
nginx_cont_1  | 2022/06/01 12:00:23 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "web_cont_1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:12
```

Note that when i do docker-compose run containername commande, i get the error
ERROR: No such service: containername

containername is the name i get when i run docker-compose ps

Any hints?

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  nginx_cont:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/nginx/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/static
      - mediafiles:/app/media
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 3000:3000
      - 6006:6006
    depends_on:
      - web_cont
    networks:
      spa_network:

  web_cont:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/static
      - mediafiles:/app/media
      - sqlite_db:/app/db  
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./env/prod-sample
    networks:
      spa_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.2

networks:
  spa_network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16

volumes:
  sqlite_db:
  staticfiles:
  mediafiles:
```

Thank you

Comment: You should be able to use the Compose service name in the `proxy_pass` line; you do not need `networks:`, `container_name:` options, or to look up the variable Docker-internal IP address.  What does your Compose setup look like, and what result do you get when you try to make this call?

Comment: ok thanks for your insight. i've added the docker-compose.yml. the fact docker-compose run containername is not working should be an alert something is not working properly with the service names no?
I need to keep the networks: because i have many docker containers running and i would have port conflicts if i dont keep the networks:

Comment: Internally each container has its own IP address.  This is an implementation detail you don't need to worry about, except that there aren't port conflicts if you have six containers all listening on port 80.  Using the `default` network that [Compose provides for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) should be fine.